# Split a string in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to split a single string into array or JSON format. Kindly help in doing that in angular js controller (not in HTML view).

The string format is like,

```
string="Name1;Email1;ID1~Name2;Email2;ID2"
```

None of the ways I tried worked. I tried using string.split('~') but I am getting an error as split is not a function.

```
myView.service('ViewService', [function () {
var temp = [];
var fstring = [];
this.SplitUser = function (userstring) {
    debugger;
    //temp = userstring.split('~');
    angular.forEach(userstring, function (value, key) {
        fstring.push({
            'Name': temp.split(';')[i],
            'EmailID': temp.split(';')[i++],
            'ID': temp.split(';')[i++]
        });
    })
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(fstring);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Post all the ways that you tried.

Comment: `var arr = string.split('~');` should work. post the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to loop the `temp` array.not `userstring`.Also when you are pushing to the `fstring` array remove the `i` and use the position as a number

```
 fstring.push({
   'Name': value.split(';')[0],
   'EmailID': value.split(';')[1],
   'ID': value.split(';')[2]
 );
```

change your service like this.

```
.service('ViewService', [function () {
var temp = [];
var fstring = [];
this.SplitUser = function (userstring) {
    debugger;
    temp = userstring.split('~');
    angular.forEach(temp, function (value, key) {
        fstring.push({
            'Name': value.split(';')[0],
            'EmailID': value.split(';')[1],
            'ID': value.split(';')[2]
        });
    })
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(fstring);
    return temp;
}
}])
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,ViewService){
   var string="Name1;Email1;ID1~Name2;Email2;ID2";
   ViewService.SplitUser(string)

}).service('ViewService', [function () {
var temp = [];
var fstring = [];
this.SplitUser = function (userstring) {
    debugger;
    temp = userstring.split('~');
    angular.forEach(temp, function (value, key) {
        fstring.push({
            'Name': value.split(';')[0],
            'EmailID': value.split(';')[1],
            'ID': value.split(';')[2]
        });
    })
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(fstring);
    return temp;
}
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting an error like 
TypeError: temp.split is not a function at

Comment: dont use `temp.split`use `temp = userstring.split('~');`  check the service again

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "Name1;Email1;ID1~Name2;Email2;ID2";
// Initial split in entries
var splitStrings = string.split('~');
var objects = [];
for(var i = 0; i < splitStrings.length; i++) {
    // split into properties
    var objProps = splitStrings[i].split(';');
    var myObj = {};
    myObj.name = objProps[0];
    myObj.mail = objProps[1];
    myObj.id = objProps[2];
    objects.push(myObj);
}

console.log(objects);
```

This should split your string and put it into objects. Then add those objects into an array.

If you want to use JSON and have control over the code that sends you the message I would suggest you use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() instead.

This sollution expect a strict structure like the one you posted and has no eror handling.

Comment: Getting an error like 
TypeError: temp.split is not a function at

Comment: Do those snippets work for you or do they also return the error?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = [];
 var  string="Name1;Email1;ID1~Name2;Email2;ID2"
 var arr = string.split('~');
 angular.forEach(arr, function (value, key) {
   
        $scope.name.push({
            'Name': value.split(';')[0],
            'EmailID': value.split(';')[1],
            'ID': value.split(';')[2]
        });
    })
    console.log($scope.name);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```